# How to insert array into hashtable w/o initializing in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, hash, initialization, hashmap

I have a hashmap initialized as follows:

```
Hashmap<String[][], Boolean> tests = new Hashmap<String [][], Boolean>();
```

I would like to insert into tests without having to initialize the key:

```
tests.put({{"a"}, {"a"}}, true);
```

However, Java doesn't seem to let me do this. It works if I do it like this:

```
String[][] hi = {{"a"}, {"a"}};
tests.put(hi, true);
```

Is there any way to avoid the latter and get the former working?

Can someone also explain the reasoning behind this error?

Thanks

Comment: thanks to the quick answers, I edited my question to ask for the reason behind this error, if anyone is up for answering that as well.

Comment: FYI, you can't really use arrays as keys in a `HashMap` in the first place -- it'll use reference equality, not value equality.

Comment: thank you very much, i was wondering why it wasn't working :)

Comment: Yep.  The simplest solution is generally to create a wrapper class around the array with proper `equals` and `hashCode` implementations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can write like this:

```
tests.put(new String[][] {{"a"}, {"a"}}, true);
```

This is often referred to as an *anonymous array* or a *just-in-time* array.

Answer (score 4):

In your case you would have to use

```
tests.put(new String[][]{{"a"}, {"a"}}, true);
```

because as you noticed `{{"a"}, {"a"}}`

```
String[][] hi = {{"a"}, {"a"}};
```

can be used only while creating reference to array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
tests.put(new String[][]{{"hello", "goodbye"},{"hi", "bye"}}, true);
```

Comment: The OP wants 2D String array.

Comment: @JigarJoshi: Almost there, you still need the extra `[]`s. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is almost definitely *not* what you want.

Arrays in Java get their equality and hash code from `Object` -- which is to say, based on their reference identity. So:

```
String[] a = { "hello" }; // create one array
String[] b = { "hello" }; // create a different array with the same contents
assert a != b; // the two references are to different objects
assert ! a.equals(b); // they're not equal
assert a.hashCode() != b.hashCode(); // neither are their hashes (probably)
```

`a` and `b` will not be equal, and their hash codes will almost certainly not be equal, since they are different objects. This means that if you use an array as the key to a hash map, you won't be able to retrieve the value using an key but the exact one that you created it with: any other array will have a different hash code and will be non-equal, and therefore won't be considered an equivalent key.

The solution is to replace the `String[][]` with a `List<List<String>>`. Lists define equality and hash codes based on their contents, so a list containing `[ "hello" ]` is equal to any other list containing `[ "hello" ]`:

```
List<String> x = Arrays.asList("hello");
List<String> y = Arrays.asList("hello");
assert x != y; // the two lists are different objects
assert x.equals(y); // but they're equal
assert x.hashCode() == y.hashCode(); // and so are their hash codes
```

Now you can use the lists as keys. Keep in mind that once a list is a key to the map, it's not allowed to change values. Doing so will probably break the hash map, because the list's hash code will have changed, but the map won't know about it, so the map will look for it in the wrong hash bucket.

The easiest options here are:

1. be sure that nobody else has a reference to that same List object and might change it
2. create a deep copy of the List before you put it into the map (that is, copy the "inner" lists as well as the "outer" one)

For the second option, it'd be something like:

```
// copy the outer list
List<List<String>> outerCopy = new ArrayList<List<String>>( originalList );
ListIterator<List<String>> listIterator = outerCopy.listIterator();
while (listIterator.hasNext()) {
    // make a copy of the inner list
    List<String> innerCopy = new ArrayList<String>( listIterator.next() );
    listIterator.set(innerCopy);
}
```